# HTML5 SVG - Text Positioning

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to position a `<text>` element in HTML5 SVG by giving it a top margin. Let' say, I wanted the `<text>` element to have a top margin of 10px. This will not work:

```
<svg style="height: 100px; border: 1px solid black">
    <text fill="#000" x="10" y="10" font-size="50" font-family="Arial">
        <tspan>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</tspan>
    </text>    
</svg>
```

The problem is, that for SVG text elements, the `y` distance is measured from the bottom line of the text, not the top. This code produces text where only the lower 10px are visible. So, we have to add the `font-size` value to the `y` value to get the margin right:

```
<svg style="height: 100px; border: 1px solid black">
    <text fill="#000" x="10" y="60" font-size="50" font-family="Arial">
        <tspan>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</tspan>
    </text>    
</svg>
```

At least, that was what I thought. But this does not work either. Now, the top margin is too large, as you can see in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yy8gS/2/. I want the top margin to be the same as the left margin, which is clearly not the case. In fact, a `y` value of 48 looks about right but I have no idea why, or how I could calculate this value for arbitrary margins and font sizes. It seems to me that the `font-size` value is not the actual text height value used by SVG for positioning.

Can anybody help me with this? Is what I am trying to do even possible with SVG?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Setting [dominant-baseline](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#BaselineAlignmentProperties) should give you what you need, perhaps `dominant-baseline="hanging"` so that the text position is based on the top of the text rather than the baseline.

If you want to know how tall the font is then you should call [getExtentOfChar](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#__svg__SVGTextContentElement__getExtentOfChar) to determine it rather than assuming you get a font with a font-size which is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: ```dominant-baseline: hanging;```

Comment: text {
  dominant-baseline: text-before-edge;
}

Comment: I like this solution, however I found that it's not yet supported by Safari.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `em`'s in `y` and `dy`-attributes!

This solved my problem at least:

```html
<div>
  <p>working: margin as y-value:</p>
  <svg style="height: 100px; border: 1px solid black">
    <text fill="#000" x="10" y="1em" font-size="50" font-family="Arial">
      <tspan>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</tspan>
    </text>    
  </svg>
</div>
```